# Greedy behaviour of the `+` and `*` operators

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

I have a variable,

```
var inp = "B123213";
```

Now when i apply the below regex,

```
var rg = /\d+/;
```

and perform `String` `match` operation,

```
console.log(inp.match(rg));
```

I get the output as `123213`, denoting that the expression is greedy. But when i use `*`, instead of `+`, the expression does not return a match. Please help me understand why an empty match is returned. Shouldn't it too be returning the same result.

Since the doc says about `?`,

> If used immediately after any of the quantifiers *, +, ?, or {}, makes
>   the quantifier non-greedy (matching the fewest possible characters),
>   as opposed to the default, which is greedy (matching as many
>   characters as possible). For example, applying /\d+/ to "123abc"
>   matches "123". But applying /\d+?/ to that same string matches only
>   the "1".

I would expect an empty match only on applying `/\d*?/`.

Comment: an awesome site for learning and playing with regex is http://regex101.com/ I has helped me out greatly learning and playing with regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your string to `123213` and it will match all the digits.

**The engine won't advance unless it has to.**

Here it sees a `B`123213 and it can match `nothing` ie `\d*` at that position,
so it does.

So, its really about position first, quantifiers second.

Comment: **The engine won't advance unless it has to.** That is spot on, +1

Answer (score 3):

when `*` is used it returns three matches.One empty and second the same as one returned by `+`.The empty is due to the fact that when string is consumed `\d*` can match the empty string at the end and at start as well.You are getting the first match.Make it a group to see all matches.

see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/gT6kI4/2

Comment: Will check out the group. But even then the match with the highest number of elements should have been returned, am i wrong?

Comment: OP doesn't have `g` flag in his regex

Comment: @BatScream if you use `g` flag all matches will be returned.else only the first one that is empty one.See http://regex101.com/r/gT6kI4/3

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think the explanation is a bit better in sln's answer, +1.